# How to fill with color a complex SVG image?

Tags: svg

I have an independent SVG image with no filling (fill="none").

[image]
I would like to fill it with color, but when I change fill="none" to fill="blue" for all paths, my file becomes a blueish mess:
[image]

Source SVG file: https://ufile.io/yaj33

Answer (score 2):

Your SVG is not "clean". It is made up of several hundred open (ie. not closed) path elements. If you want to be able to fill your drawing easily, you'll need to make an SVG with a smaller number of closed shapes, perhaps one for the head, one for each arm and leg, and two open paths for the eyes.